# different inventory levels for same SKU multi store

Tags: multistore, inventory, sku

We have a *Canadian website* and a *US website*. All products are shared. But we have two warehouses, one in each country. Therefore we need different stock levels for our websites.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact situation as you.

In Magento SKUS are globally unique... and can only have 1 inventory level.

First off... DO NOT use an extension (AITOC multi-inventory) for this. Just don't. The answer we came to after much debate and asking around was to simply NOT use the same product. We clone the products but with a suffix on the SKU and URL slug. Now we have separate inventories... Yes we have to maintain 2 skus... but that was acceptable to us.

In our US store we have a Product with SKU  AB12345-XYZ
The Same Product in Canada store is SKU  AB12345-XYZ-CA

Then we remove the -CA from any canada sku when we integrate to our ERP or warehouse.

Likewise URL slugs are globally unique so we also append -ca to the URL slug.

The other reason you want to do this is that you want the sku to have a base price in the native currency of each store (in our case US and Canada prices are NOT an exact exchanged rate... but have their own set market prices)

Comment: What's wrong with AITOC's multi-inventory extension? Care to elbaorate? We've installed it and did some simple tests, and it seems to work OK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will have two websites so the URL slug is not necessary. First website will be shop.mysite.com/ca and other one will ne shop.mysite.com/us.

Comment: But I wonder why you advice NOT to use any extension? My company is not thrilled with having 2 SKUS for each product.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with a solution where each location uses different SKUs for many reasons:

1. How do you get unified reports on how a SKU performs?
2. How will it be possible to transfer quantities between your different inventory locations?
3. How will you be able to make purchase orders to your suppliers and to monitor the availability levels of several different SKUs that are essentially the same one?

This sounds like a non-scalable workaround.

You can find numerous extensions that support this, many are featured in Magento Connect. Try to search for "Inventory Management for Multiple Locations" and you will find a range of choices.

Comment: Thanks Dimitris, that was my first idea. I wonder why Moonman67 advice not to use any extension though

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 introduced MSI Inventory Management use this to resolve this problem.

for More info go to magento devdocs

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/
```

This will help you.

Happy Coding!!